# How do I diagnose "There was an error launching the application"?

Tags: launcher, .desktop

I created a `my-app.desktop` file for a program I wrote. When I double-click it, I get the error message "**There was an error launching the application**". How can I get more detailed information about what the problem is?

I saw a reference to a "details" section of the dialog box, but there is nothing like that present in the one I see. If I were on my Mac, I'd open the Console app to see if any errors were logged, but I haven't learned of anything similar on Ubuntu.

(Note that unlike other similarly-titled questions, I am not asking what's wrong with this particular .desktop file; I want to know how to find out in general.)

Comment: I would just run the Exec line from the terminal and see what the output tells you, but are you sure the desktop file is ok? maybe you should check and run it from the terminal as well.

Comment: @Jacob If there is a way to "run it from the terminal" that puts something useful on stderr, that would constitute an answer to this question.

Comment: Jacob just gave you the way: open a terminal and run the exact command you have as `Exec`, that should give you more info. We can't tell you any more unless we know more details about what you're attempting.

Comment: @terdon I tried that, and it turned out that (as the *next* problem) the environment was different in a way that mattered. I want to know how to get more information out of the **normal launch process** so that I'm not *guessing* at what's different.

Comment: Well, that _is_ the way. I'm not sure I understand, the terminal should print some output which apparently led you to the conclusion you reached right? There's no catch-all here, what was the program? A compiled executable? A shell script? Perl? Python? Does it expect to be run by a specific user? It all depends on the details and running it in the terminal is always the first step.

Comment: @terdon Empirically, running it in the terminal is different — I tried and it was different (in particular a different `PATH`). I want to know how to get **exactly the same environment** as a normal launch but with more diagnostic info.

Comment: A bit offtopic, but 9 times of 10 that problem airs it is special characters, like spaces, in `Exec=` path. Remember, you should have `Exec=` in quotes and `Path=` without quotes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a trick you can use. Create a wrapper script for your application that will launch it and capture the error output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Launch 'yourapp' and capture its standard error output
/path/to/yourapp 2>~/myapp.log
```

Save that as `~/foo.sh` and make it executable with `chmod +x ~/foo.sh`. Now, point your desktop launcher to it instead. Something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.0
Type=Application
Exec=/home/kevin/foo.sh
Terminal=true
Comment=My app!
```

That will redirect any error messages to `~/myapp.log` and you can examine them at your leisure. You can use `2>>~/myapp.log` if you want successive error messages to be appended to the file instead of overwriting it.

---

As an aside, the reason that the `$PATH` is different is because you are probably setting your `$PATH` in `~/.bahsrc` which is not read by the graphical environment. It is also a bad idea since the `$PATH` will be set every time you open a new terminal and that is needless overhead. Use `~/.profile` for this instead. For more details on which files are read when see [here](https://superuser.com/a/695397/151431) and for more on which file should be used for what, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/183956/151431).

Comment: Didn't found the problem this way, but the wrapper was working, so I just kept the wrapper as the executable.

Answer (score 27):

Found an answer to this question here: https://askubuntu.com/a/836842

Try this :

```
desktop-file-validate my-app.desktop
```

It outputs errors in your `.desktop` file. For example mine returned :

```
error: first group is not "Desktrop Entry"
```

So once I corrected the typo to `Desktop Entry`, the script ran successfully.

Comment: This should be the solution. The chosen solution above is tedious and fragile.

Answer (score 12):

By running the following command in terminal:

```
awk -F= '/Exec=/{system($2)}' your_desktop_file.desktop
```

I am sure that you will find out if there is an error or not in your command assigned to the `Exec` field from inside of your .desktop file.

Comment: I've a similar problem. i execute your command and my.desktop file work perfectly. But when i double click it ,it shows  There was an error launching the application

Comment: This answer is kind of funny, since (even though I don't think it does any-much-more than running _Exec_ value in the shell) it made me realize ***TryExec*** key was my problem.

Comment: If you have a complicated Exec command, you have to wrap it in bash script, like it shown in the accepted answer (and don't forget to give it `chmod a+x your.sh` executable rights)

Comment: Thank you, calling this made me find there was a wrong path in my Exec= line at the *.desktop file I'm editing

Answer (score 3):

usually, the terminal(-output) gives you a lot of useful information, both on the application as well as the desktop file. An example:
if I run my application from the terminal, typing the command in the terminal, the application starts.

However, if there is something wrong, you can expect an output like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/werkmap_2.0/uploaded_versions/2.1.2/32_en_ppa    /qle-2.1.2/code/qle_quicklisteditor", line 4044, in <module>
    MainWindow()
  File "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/werkmap_2.0/uploaded_versions/2.1.2/32_en_ppa   /qle-2.1.2/code/qle_quicklisteditor", line 51, in __init__
    self.load_sectons()
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'load_sectons'
jacob@Jacobwerkkamer:~/Bureaublad/werkmap_2.0/uploaded_versions/2.1.2/32_en_ppa   /qle-2.1.2/code$
```

which gives you a lot of usefull information, even the line in your application that causes the error. (I messed it up on purpose)

The same with the desktop file, just open a terminal in the directory of the .desktop file and drag it on to the terminal. If you for example remove the `Exec=` line from a .desktop file, the terminal will tell you it cannot find the command to execute.

To test if the application gives an error, just run what you put after the`Exec=` string.

The terminal output is usually very specific and useful in bug reports, like [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/jonb.homelauncher/+bug/1283167).

Comment: I know about how to use a terminal and how to troubleshoot a program launch in general. Assuming this approach, what I need to know is **how to reproduce the conditions of a .desktop launch accurately in the terminal**.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was a missing `Icon=` line (which seems like a stupid requirement for a working launcher). My full .desktop file now looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LiClipse
Comment=Variant of Eclipse
Exec=/home/tsbertalan/bin/liclipse
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=/home/tsbertalan/usr/liclipse/icon.xpm
```

Which isn't particularly robust to changes in user, but whatever.

Comment: Thanks! `Icon` seems to be required to run, although `desktop-file-validate` did not complain about it.

Answer (score 1):

This might help other people - this is the [official spec of the desktop launcher files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)

The important section is : Recognized desktop entry keys - which shows you which values you need.

Answer (score 0):

When I really can't figure it out, I:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ln -s /my/binary/thatIwanttorun mybinary
```

Then right click on the default icon that's created and point to a better graphic.

Comment: and there should be a <cr> after "cd ~/Desktop"