# .desktop file running sh script "There was an error launching the application."

Tags: command-line, .desktop

I have a .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=RunMe
Exec=run.sh
```

When I double click the .desktop file, I get `There was an error launching the application.`

my `run.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
xulrunner-sdk/bin/xulrunner-stub --app xulrunner-sdk/bin/application.ini 2>~log.log
```

Double clicking on `run.sh` and clicking `run` runs the application fine. Both `run.sh` and my `.desktop` are executable.

What do I need to change in my desktop file to make this work?

Comment: Use a full pathname on the Exec line.

Comment: I tried that, same issue, but ideally I want this to be portable anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%k` is the desktop file path, use it with `sh` to relative .desktop:

- Change current working directory (`pwd`), Then `run.sh` & commands inside all will run from there:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Terminal=true
  Name=Run Me
  Exec=sh -c "cd `dirname %k`; run.sh"
  ```
- Otherwise, passing it as parameter to `run.sh` and use it explicitly when you need inside `run.sh`:

  `run.desktop`

  ```
      [Desktop Entry]
      Type=Application
      Terminal=true
      Name=Run Me
      Exec=sh -c "`dirname %k`/run.sh `dirname %k`"
  ```

  `run.sh`

  ```
      #!/bin/sh
      $1/xulrunner-sdk/bin/xulrunner-stub --app $1/xulrunner-sdk/bin/application.ini 2>$1/~log.log
  ```

Reference: [How can I set the 'Path' variable in a .desktop file to be relative to the location where the desktop file is located?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47775/how-can-i-set-the-path-variable-in-a-desktop-file-to-be-relative-to-the-locat/345123#345123)

Comment: Tried 'Exec=bash -c "export PATH=$PATH:`dirname %k`; sh run.sh;"' but still nothing happens on the double click.

Comment: @Kiksy, I didn't notice that you are using other relative path inside `run.sh`. Change current working directory (pwd) should work, or passing it as parameter. Updated answer

Answer (score 7):

To figure out what exactly is the error as you asked

> What do I need to change in my desktop file to make this work?

After a lot of research, I found that you can indeed validate your desktop file with this command

```
desktop-file-validate your-file-here.desktop
```

This was the hidden command I was trying to find since hours. This, Saved my day :-)

This command will show you warning and errors wherever you have gone wrong.
Credits : [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2283698)

Comment: Great find, but it doesn't actually execute the Exec command.

Answer (score 1):

- Goto /usr/share/app-install/desktop
- right click on your specific application
- go to properties
- copy the command section
- execute same from terminal

Answer (score -1):

1. Put your script, (the orig. one) in a bin directory in your PATH if not already.
2. Rename the script & lose the extension, eg, `run1`
3. edit your .desktop to reflect new name, eg. `Exec=run1`