# 'mpsyt' command runs from terminal but not from .desktop file?

Tags: .desktop

I have installed mps-youtube program with pip.
The program runs in terminal with the command 'mpsyt', no matter from which location i run the terminal.
I have created a .desktop file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MPS-YouTube
Exec=mpsyt
Terminal=true
Icon=/home/john/Pictures/Icons/YouTube_01.png
```

But when I execute the shortcut it says 'there was an error launching the application'.

I also tried with `Exec=sh -c 'mpsyt'` but it does nothing, in this case even massage is missing!
I think it is due to the pip installation because when I install this program from the Synaptic the shortcut works fine but the version is older. Also the command is not recognized from Alt+F2 box.

So how can I see what is causing this error?

Comment: Did you try to run other commands? Amd did you make it executable?

Comment: @thangdc94 Yes if I change `mpsyt` with `gedit` it opens gedit!

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436999/how-do-i-diagnose-there-was-an-error-launching-the-application) to debug your desktop entry. You think you should try to use absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to thangdc94 for the comments. I have found the solution - the exec line should be `Exec=bash -i -c "mpsyt"`. Now it works perfect.