# Disable bluetooth (turn on "Bluetooth Airplane Mode") on startup

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, budgie

I want to configure my operating system so that bluetooth is turned off by default after starting the computer. Currently it is activated on startup, and I have to click on the bluetooth icon in the system bar to activate "bluetooth airplane mode" to turn it off manually.

I already set the `Autoenable` value to false in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` (updated after mentioned in @Frantique's
answer). This did not change the default behavior after restarting my system.

How to disable bluetooth by default without losing the option to activate it if needed?

Using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, ubuntu-budgie-desktop Version: 0.65.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a startup application* for this command:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Rfkill --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill' 'BluetoothAirplaneMode' '<true>'
```

Also you can change the **Autoenable** value to **false** in **/etc/bluetooth/main.conf**.

* <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and run the **gnome-session-properties** command

Comment: Thanks! [Startup applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en) don't seem to be supported in Budgie. I already set `Autoenable` to false though, I will this to my question. I will try to make an autostart script in one of the (many) alternatives described here then: https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: I placed a `.desktop` file to execute a shell script with the gdbus line in my `~/.config/autostart` folder and rebooted my system, but bluetooth is still active after startup.

Comment: The shell script has #!/bin/bash as first line and it is executable?

Comment: I missed the #!/bin/bash line, but still no success after reboot. I will add a line to echo into some log file to ensure that the script is actually executed at all.

Comment: your script works when executed directly, but it also disables Wi-Fi, probably activating airplane mode for all network devices. To restrict this to "Bluetooth Airplane Mode" (this is what it is called in the menu) only, the setting must be 'BluetoothAirplaneMode'.

Comment: Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/questions/436999/how-do-i-diagnose-there-was-an-error-launching-the-application I found that `Icon` is a required entry in a `.desktop` file to make it work (although `desktop-file-validate` did not complain when it was missing). Now I finally made it work on startup.